# What is the best approach that is adopted by the most browsers to make home screen icons for "Add to home screen" feature

Tags: android, browser, favicon, homescreen

I am developing a browser running on Android. I want to add a feature called "Add to home screen" which makes a shortcut icon on home screen for the webpage shown on the current browser tab. What do you think is the best solution to make the home screen icon?

I decided to use the Favicon of each website. While I tried to use the same function in other browsers such as Chrome, I found that making an icon from Favicon seems to be very common, so I tried to find the best way to get Favicon. I found two easy solutions;

(1) Use API in https://realfavicongenerator.net/

(2) Use API provided by Google; https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=xxx.xxx.xxx

However, the first one needs to be paid. The second one looks like what I want, but the returned favicons are too small (16x16).

I concluded that both are not the right ones for me.

Lastly, I decided to use Jsoup to get Favicon info that is included in  section. However, I found two issues.

(1) Not every site specify the URL of Favicon within  tags.

(2) Though I can find the URL of Favicon, the size of it is often too small to use.

I just wanted to know what is the best approach that is adopted by the most browsers to make home screen icons for "Add to home screen" feature.

Comment: RealFaviconGenerator's author speaking, is your project a free/open source tool? If so, you could use the service for free.

Comment: Thanks, philippe_b. Unfortunately, mine is not free/open source project. Anyway, thanks for your info. I didn't know that.